# IDA decompiler macro

Tags: ida, hexrays, decompiler, float

What is the purpose of `COERCE_FLOAT` and `COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT` macros in the Hex Rays decompiled code below?

```
double __cdecl sub_401580(float a1)
{
  unsigned int v1; // eax@1
  double v2; // st7@1
  float v4; // [sp+10h] [bp+4h]@1
  float v5; // [sp+10h] [bp+4h]@1

  v1 = LODWORD(a1) & 0x80000000;
  v4 = 1.273239493370056 * a1 - a1 * 0.4052847325801849 * COERCE_FLOAT(LODWORD(a1) & 0x7FFFFFFF);
  v2 = v4;
  v5 = v4 * v4;
  return (float)(v5
               * ((v5 * COERCE_FLOAT(v1 ^ COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT(-0.0032225901))
                 + COERCE_FLOAT(v1 | COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT(0.015124941)))
                * v5
                + COERCE_FLOAT(v1 | COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT(0.20363937)))
               + v2 * 0.7844448685646057);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: that is the question :P

Comment: macro doing ? COERCE_FLOAT and COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT

Comment: please help me to simply the code

Answer (score 6):

`COERCE_TYPE(x)` is the same thing as `*(TYPE *)&x`. Hex-Rays uses `COERCE_...` macros when `&x` is illegal. For example:

```
COERCE_DOUBLE(__PAIR__(i1,i2))
```

Is the same as `*(double *)&__PAIR__(i1, i2)`, but since `&` can not be applied to calls, we end up seeing `COERCE`.

Its name correctly conveys its meaning.

Comment: Are You The Ilfak Guilfanov ?  Welcome to RESE

Answer (score 1):

**I'd read this (and probably it is a mistake) as** treating binary content of the variable as a variable of another type, something like this:

- coerce float is `*((float*)&var)`, where var was of the same size as float, supposedly 4 bytes.
- coerce unsigned int is `*((unsigned int*)&var)`, where var was of the same size as unsigned int.

As far as I remember 32 bit platforms treating unsigned int and float as a values of 4 bytes length.

Comment: Thanx for Your Answer, where all these macro defined in ida decompiler, is there any header file

Comment: I don;t know anything about header file where ii is defined. It is only suggestion.

Comment: I'm with @Arun, I would love to know where these macros are defined so I can go look them up.

Answer (score 1):

coerce_* functions are generally a little more coercive that a simple casting, I would assume their meaning as follows:

```
   #define VALUE_SIZE (sizeof(int))

struct VALUE_TYPE {
    char contents[VALUE_SIZE];
};

struct VALUE_TYPE COERCE_FLOAT(float arg) {
    struct VALUE_TYPE rv;
    memcpy(&arg, rv.contents, sizeof arg);
    return rv;
}

struct VALUE_TYPE COERCE_INT(int arg) {
    struct VALUE_TYPE rv;
    memcpy(&arg, rv.contents, sizeof arg);
    return rv;
}

struct VALUE_TYPE COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT(unsigned int arg) {
    struct VALUE_TYPE rv;
    memcpy(&arg, rv.contents, sizeof arg);
    return rv;
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37198532/912236

The reason for their use may relate to how the ABI passes floats vs how it passes integers.  There is no difference in Windows 32-bit code (either stdcall or cdecl), but in x64 float's and integers are passed in different registers.

It's possible that those macro may make no difference to compilation of a 32-bit target, and are just there to ensure (or inform the reader/compiler) of the expected type, but that's pure conjecture on my part.